# Shirk unknowingly

Tags: blessings-of-allah

My mother was having a tough time but she stopped doing shirk long time ago but because of her predicaments she started doing shirk again and she introduced me into it but I was completely unawear that it was a sin because the shirk man would say this is quranic writing and would tell us to say Bisimilah because I was never a muslimah I never knew this was wronged untill one day God introduced Islam into me I started praying eventhou im still practising to wear hidjab anyways I threw away every shirk iteam that I was given but because I did shirk unknowing or knowing will I go to hell? And also im constantly thinking of death what does this signify plz help me I'm in serious depression

Answer (score 1):

Islam erases what before it .. The prophet Muhammad said 
and to the people who said the god is Christ, the son of Mary he say to them (Do they not repent to God? and ask forgiveness from him? And God is Forgiving,and Merciful)surat al almaaida  ayah 17,,,he said in the end of the ayah And God is Forgiving,and Merciful to tell them if the ask the forgiveness  he will forgive them because he is Forgiving,and Merciful
and he said to Israelis when the disobey Mouse and do  shirk (Those who did bad things then repented after that and believed that your Lord after that would have a merciful gopher)Surat almaaida ayah 153
so if you now repented  and believed and don not back to shirk  the god will forgive you 
our god is God is Forgiving,and Merciful

Comment: Massallah may Allah bless you

Comment: and bless you ... please if my answer help you accept it